# How To Use Paypal Payout PHP API

Tags: php, paypal, require

I'm using PHP and I want to send money to users who have sold their products on my platform. For this I'm trying to use Paypal Payouts, I've found this link here with an example code for a [single payout](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payouts/CreateSinglePayout.html).

My problem is that, I'm not that good in PHP and I have no clue how this actually works. The latter part of the script is more or less understandable however, I'm really unsure about these lines here:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
$payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();
$senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
```

What is `bootstrap.php` and why is it necessary for this paypal payout system? Also I need to know how do these objects here work `new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader()` I really do not understand the syntax here.

Can someone explain what these three lines exactly mean and why they are needed for the paypal payout and how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK#deprecation-notice) and should not be used for any new integration.

On the list of current SDKs you will find the [Payouts PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK).

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you are saying. However for me the PayPal Documentation is very hard to understand. I'm using PHP and I have no access to the server, so I cannot install anything. Can you tell me how I can integrate the Payout PHP SDK within my PHP Web-Project? If you can give me an example code that would be more helpful.

Comment: I don't know more than what's explained in the above 2nd link. There's an example, and there's a link to some Samples. Since you have limited access to your server you'll probably find it easiest to get it working locally first, and then upload your completed code alongside the SDK to your server when you are prepared to publish it.

Comment: Do I just drop the `PaypalPayoutsSDK` - folder into my file system? I've analyzed the samples a little bit. I think I can get it to work, but I'm not sure if I'm "installing" the SDK correctly when I drop it into my file system?

Comment: The documentation suggests you clone the repository and then run a couple composer commands. You can then figure out the resulting file structure and what parts of it our needed for the samples to run